# print variable in modal box

Tags: php, html, modal-dialog

I want to print button `SUBMIT` with the loop count. My code is something like this.

```
for($i=0; $i&lt;3; $i++) {
//To create modal box for FLAG
echo '&lt;a href="#id02"&gt;FLAG&lt;/a&gt;
&lt;div id="id02" class="modal"&gt;
    &lt;div class="modal-dialog"&gt;
        &lt;div class="modal-content"&gt;
            &lt;header class="container"&gt;
                &lt;a href="#" class="closebtn"&gt;x&lt;/a&gt;
                &lt;h2&gt;FLAG&lt;/h2&gt;
            &lt;/header&gt;
            &lt;div class="container"&gt;
                &lt;form action="" method="post"&gt;
                    &lt;input type="radio" name="for" value="spam"&gt;spam&lt;/input&gt;&lt;/br&gt;
                        This is posted to promote some product or service.&lt;/br&gt;
                    &lt;input type="radio" name="for" value="rude or abusive"&gt;rude or abusive&lt;/input&gt;&lt;/br&gt;
                        Content is rude and is abusive&lt;/br&gt;
                    &lt;input type="radio" name="for" value="moderator intervention needed"&gt;moderator intervention needed&lt;/input&gt;&lt;/br&gt;
                        content requires human intervention&lt;/br&gt;
                    &lt;button class="flag_button" name="q_flag'.$i.'"&gt;Submit'.$i.'&lt;/button&gt;
                &lt;/form&gt;
            &lt;/div&gt;
            &lt;footer class="container"&gt;
                &lt;p&gt;footer&lt;/p&gt;
            &lt;/footer&gt;
        &lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;';
}
```

CSS code for it goes like this

```
/* Add animation (Chrome, Safari, Opera) */
@-webkit-keyframes example {
from {
    top:-100px; 
    opacity:0;
    }
to {
    top:0px;
    opacity:1;
}   
}
@keyframes expample {
from {
    top:-100px;
    opacity:0;
}
to {
    top:0px;
    opacity:1;
}
}
.modal {
display:none;
position:fixed;
left:0;
top:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
overflow:auto;
background-color:rgb(0,0,0);
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
.modal:target {
display:table;
position:absolute;
}
.modal-dialog {
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
}
.modal-dialog .modal-content {
margin:auto;
background-color:#f3f3f3;
position:relative;
padding:0;
outline:0;
border:1px #777 solid;
text-align:justify;
width:80%;
box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
-webkit-animation-name: example;
-webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
animation-name:example;
animation-duration:0.5s;
}
.closebtn {
text_decoration:none;
float:right;
font-size:35px;
font-weight:bold;
color:#fff;
}
.closebtn:hover, .closebtn:focus {
color: #000;
text_decoration:none;
cursor:pointer;
}
.container {
padding: 2px 16px;
}
header {
background-color:#5cb85c;
font-size: 25px;
color:white;
}
```

But it doesn't prints the variable `$i` when it is taken within `echo`. Inside 'modal' class it sets value of 'i' to 0. And without the CSS code it works fine.
Am I going wrong somewhere? If you need more information, please feel free to ask.

Comment: I test your code and works fine! but, in your loop create div with same id, id02

Comment: I get the same as @Cuchu. Code labels submit buttons fine. div id is duped, but that's because its hardcoded.

Comment: @dewd I have added the CSS code associated with it. Without CSS it works well.

Answer (score 1):

Links call the same modal box (#id02). Change your code like this example below:

```
for($i=0; $i<3; $i++) {
  //To create modal box for FLAG
  echo '<a href="#id0'.$i.'">FLAG</a>
    <div id="id0'.$i.'" class="modal">
      <!-- You modal's code -->
    </div>
  </div>';
}
```

Comment: Its not working for me. Its not showing anything on my browser.

Comment: Nothing is visible or is this HTML code hidden by CSS rules?

Comment: Yes. This is HTML code hidden in CSS rules. Without CSS it works fine.

Comment: So the PHP works fine. You should check your JS code and/or your CSS properties.

Comment: @elliradnaw I have added my css code above and I am not using js here.

Comment: Seems weird, it's work [here](https://jsbin.com/disewapiqo/1/edit?html,css,output). It may depend on the browser you use, some do not support all CSS3 properties. You can check on the [W3Schools' website](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_browsersupport.asp) (NOTE: I am using the HTML generated code, but as I said, the php loop works with me)

Comment: I just see what's wrong! Sorry I focused on the fact that the modal should appear. In fact, the three links call the same modal (`#id02`). I changed my answer to give you a solution: add index `$i` in the modal id (JSbin [here](https://jsbin.com/komopihome/edit?html,css,output)). That should do the trick.

Comment: The trick you used is not working for me. Actually it takes sets value of 'i' to 0 inside the 'modal' class.